# .htacces redirect assets to assets folder

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my PHP site setup with a folder for each site (e.g Login), which has an Index.php file and site-specfic assets. However, some of the assets, which are required by every single page, are stored in a 'Assets' folder located directly under the highest level (does that make sense?).

I have played around with .htaccess and got this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://janberktold.com/Assets/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, my problem is: It redirects

> localhost/Login/test.css

to

> localhost/Assets/Login/test.css

instead of

> localhost/Assets/test.css

How do I get my server to redirect to the correct path?

Comment: try `/Assets/test.css` as your link url and remove .htaccess.  like `<link rel="stylesheet" ... href="/Assets/test.css" />`

Comment: @imsiso I am aware of that solution, however I want to be able to just put 'test.css' and be redirected for that. May it just be for the sake of knowing how to do it.

Comment: why do you need redirect with 301?

Comment: @tttony that's not required, I merely used it as I've seen an example using it

Comment: @JanBerktold: Do you have only one `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` or several .htaccess files one in each folder like `Login/.htaccess` etc.?

Comment: @anubhava I only have one main .htaccess.

Comment: @JanBerktold: Thanks, I provided my answer below, let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your rules with:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*/)*([^/.]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /Assets/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite if the file does not exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Rewrite only if the URI does not starts with Assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Assets

# Rewrite any assets file
RewriteRule ([^/]*).(css|js|png|jpe?g)$ Assets/$1.$2 [L]
```

This should rewrite any assets files `localhost/dir/file.css` or `localhost/dir/dir2/file.css` to `localhost/Assets/file.css`

Comment: +1 good but what about rest of assets? what about a solution with multi extension support? + how is my answer?

Comment: I have a reverse scenario here, my paths of asset folder are relative like img src="../../assets/img.png" in this manner where i cannot edit code only thing i can do is to rewrite from htaccess file. my root folder is /abc.  can u pls give me a redirect rule mentioning anything /../..assets/img.png goes like /abc/assets/img.png